# Cannot load /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml

Tags: spring

Saw same issues in others queries, but did not find the answer, hence posting it afresh.

Created a sample Helloworld service in Rest and deployed it in Tomcat-Jersey. Not using Maven.
Injecting a spring bean define in applicationContext.xml which is present in WEB-INF directory.

Deployed the service in Tomcat within Eclipse.
But when I execute the rest service, cannot find file applicationContext.xml.
Once I copy the file to **WEB-INF/classes** only, it works.

What is the way to make it work by keeping it only in **WEB-INF**?

web.xml :

```
    <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Rest service code snippet :

```
    ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath:applicationContext.xml");
```

Comment: Are you just trying to access your context from code? Any reason you are not implementing ContextAware?

Comment: depending on your contextConfigLocation that should load if file exists inside WEB-INF

Answer (score 1):

It seems reasonable to work when you drop the context descriptor under `/WEB-INF/classes` because this location is the root of `classpath`.

So try loading with below uri (without prefix) if you want to drop your *applicationContext.xml* under *WEB-INF* folder:

```
    ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml");
```

Otherwise, can you explain why are you trying to load your *applicationContext.xml* within your web application?

Alternatively, you can load your application context programatically as follows:

```
ApplicationContext ctx = WebApplicationContextUtils.getRequiredWebApplicationContext(this.getServletContext());
```

BR.

Comment: But the class from which the code is given above is just a resource class and not the servlet. Since this is a simple helloworld, I am referring to SpringServlet as the servlet to be loaded in web.xml.

Comment: Tried new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml"), but that is giving FileNotFound. Perhaps it is looking for /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml under WEB-INF/classes

Comment: Root of the classpath is /WEB-INF or /WEB-INF/classes? Since web.xml is in /WEB-INF and the starting point, right?

Comment: `classpath` referes to `/WEB-INF/classes` that is why when you moved your *applicationCOntext.xml* out there it can be loaded successfully.

**is just a resource class and not the servlet**

If it is in the same webapp so it can access the main servlet context wheter it is a servlet or not and the ServletCOntext can be injected within your resourece. But I cannot give more hints unless you give some light what you called a `resource` :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `Intellj IDEA` and having problem with  `ApplicationContext.xml` path;
Go to `File` and click `Project Structure`. Under the `Project Settings`, click `Facets`, at the `Web` Section you will see `Web Resource Directories`.  You should define `Web Resource Directory` to your `/WEB-INF` folder. If your `/WEB-INF` folder is in the subpath like below;

> /web/WEB-INF/...

Then choose `/web` directory to cover all your files.